# How to add label to edges in graphvizanim library of python?

Tags: python, graphviz

The link for graphvizanim library could be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GraphvizAnim/). Also is there any other way of creating animation of graphical algorithms using python?

my objective is to depict graphical algorithm say Dijkstra shortest path algorithm with the aid of animation.